# Ошибка 403 Forbidden?

Tags: python, http

На бесплатном сервере с поддержкой Python пытаюсь открыть url `requests.get('https://www.google.ru/')`, а мне выскакивает ошибка:

> Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden

И главное когда делаю запрос на яндекс `requests.get('https://yandex.ru')`, то скрипт успешно подключается, в чем может быть дело?

Локально на моем компьютере открывается любой запрос и гугл в том числе.

Comment: А чё за бесплатный сервер-то? Скорее всего какие-то его собственные ограничения

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com

Comment: Ну как минимум там написано «restricted outbound Internet access from your apps», да

Comment: google.ru не входит в список доступных для бесплатных пользователей. [Список доступных адресов](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/)

Comment: аа, спасибо большое)